# Аналог prompt в java

Tags: java, prompt

Увидел уроки и задания по javascript, и хотел бы это сделать на java. Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли в java аналог prompt? Scanner?

Спасибо за помощь!

Пример: [Видеоурок по javascript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wt2RJE-3us&list=PLmRNNqEA7JoM5mPIW7qITEbYEEFMSTu1n&index=4)

Answer (score 0):

Одноименный класс в джаве [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)